# Why does env variable return undefined when accessed outside the root directory?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I cannot get the values stored inside .env from files not in the root directory. I am new to using environment variables, so any help would be appreciated.

My files are structured like this:

```
folder1
  file1.js
.env
app.js
```

.env:

```
SOME_VARIABLE="rainy_sunday"
PASSWORD="apple99"
```

app.js:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
console.log(process.env.PASSWORD); //this works
```

file1.js:

```
console.log(process.env.PASSWORD); //this returns undefined
//cannot access this variable from inside file1
```

Comment: How are you excecuting `app.js` and `file1.js`? Are those the full contents of the two files?

Comment: I have those set up inside a node project. I guessed it would be easier to ask like this. My project is set up like:
app.js
.env
controllers/authController.js

I need to get the env variables from inside the controller file so I can connect to the database and register/validate users.

Comment: Not being an expert on *dotenv*, I will simply give you a superior alternative:  **[wj-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wj-config)**.  This should take care of all your configuration needs and more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the `file1.js` with `node folder1/file1.js` You need to add this dotenv config setup to `file1.js` as well:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
```

Alternately, if you import any file that has those lines already, you will have access to environment variables as those lines will run when importing. So if `file.js` imports from `app.js` that would work too.